# Docker read-only API access

Tags: docker

I need to enable read-only access to Docker API so that remote clients can execute GET requests which would allow them to list and inspect images/containers, fetch properties and query statistics.

The configuration described here http://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/#bind-docker-to-another-hostport-or-a-unix-socket implies that once remote access is granted, remote clients can execute both read and write HTTP requests.

What's the recommended configuration to limit remote API access only for reading?